# DoCmd.OpenForm Multiple criteria missing operator error

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I'm working in VBA to create an event on a form button that will open a secondary form based on two text boxes as the criteria. I'm using the following code:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Table_QA_History", , , "[Container_ID] =" & Me!Container & "And [item] ='" & Me!item & "'"
```

When I click the button I get an error message saying that there is a missing operator in query expression `'[Container_ID]=and [item] ='"`

I'm fairly new and self taught to VBA so I cannot seem to figure out what operator it is asking for.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I thnk you need a space before your And, as follows:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Table_QA_History", , , "[Container_ID] =" & Me!Container & " And [item] ='" & Me!item & "'"
```

You also need to check Me!Container and Me!item actually contain data because the message you are getting seems to indicate they aren't.